# Ionic Build android Error with Exit code 1

Tags: android

BUILD FAILED

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:716: The following error occurr
ed while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\Android\Sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:730: Compile failed; see the co
mpiler error output for details.
```

Total time: 2 seconds

> F:\todo\Ionic\Teller\src\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
>   throw e; ^ Error code 1 for command: cmd with args:
>   /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,F:\Verifast\Ionic\Te
>   ller\src\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-
>   gen ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed
>   with exit code 1

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

Please help

Answer (score 2):

try running the android tools and installing the items below:

Open the SDK manager.

```
You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-23
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)]
```

Comment: I have set-up all these and set environment variable path for these items.but still have facing issue.there is issue while building for andriod while ionic serve and ionic build bwoser is working fine.

Comment: your android SDK Api 23 ? or send me your error which you get in cmd.

Comment: Yes i have SDK "android-23". BUILD FAILED C:\Program Files\Android\Sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:716: The following error occurr ed while executing this line: C:\Program Files\Android\Sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:730: Compile failed; see the co mpiler error output for details. Total time: 2 seconds F:\Verifast\Ionic\Teller\src\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126 throw e; ^ Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,F:\todo\Ionic\Te ller\src\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant- gen –

Comment: ok you install apache ant and have you set that path in environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

> **cordova platform update android**

will fix the error. **Cordova** is always one behind the android version eg if we have android **API 24** then we have **cordova 5.x.x** supporting upto **API 23**. Hence any project is build using **API 24**(eg. using **Android Studio**) will show this error.

> For better understanding I have posted error that I got:

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApk'.
  >   A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
  >   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
  >   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
  >          Searched in the following locations:
  >              https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom
  >              https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.jar
  >          Required by:
  >              android:CordovaLib:unspecified
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.